# Laravel billing block not showing

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

Did a fresh installation of Laravel Spark 6.0 
Not able to see the billing block, did I miss something in configuration. Please see the image below:

[image]

Comment: Show your configuration.

Comment: which configuration file exactly?

Comment: First off, did you run npm install, npm run dev / prod and eventually follow https://spark.laravel.com/docs/6.0/installation#installation-types

Comment: If that doesn't help, please send a message :p

Comment: Used spark new command so everything was done. It still does not show up.

Comment: Added the team-billing argument? Sure the ServiceProvider exists?

Comment: I don't need team billing so haven't added that is it required for user billing also, as its not mentioned anywhere in the documentation? ServerProvider exists.Thanks

Comment: Show your config/app.php

Comment: Here it is https://jpst.it/1bKqX

Answer (score 0):

In SparkServiceProvider file in booted method

you need to add this line

```
Spark::canBillCustomers();
```

After this line

```
Spark::useStripe()->noCardUpFront()->trialDays(10);
```

As seen in the screenshot attached it shows now
[solved screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6wzo.png)